# Can't parse DialogFlow json response

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I know this question has been asked multiple times... but I can't figure out what happens
I've an issue while trying to parse a json response. 
Here is the json (extract)

```
{"result":{"fulfillment":{"speech":"[{\"name\":\"Pallet truck\",\"object_type\":\"machine\",\"object_id\":3279}, ...
```

I'm applying JSON parse on it like this

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

Then I have something like this

```
"result":{
  "fulfillment":{
     "speech":"[
{"name":"Pallet truck","object_type":"machine","object_id":3279},        
{"name":"CollaborativeRobot","object_type":"machine","object_id":3273},
{"name":"Bender","object_type":"machine","object_id":3997},...
```

I want only display it like that at the end :

```
Name : Pallet Truck
Name : CollaborativeRobot
Name : Bender
```

I've tried things like this

```
for (var key in obj.result.fulfillment.speech) {
      if (obj.result.fulfillment.speech.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(obj.result.fulfillment.speech[key].name.val());
      }
}
```

But I only got undefined results... I think I'm missing something while accessing the array (it's been a while without coding anything in php/js )

EDIT

[image: Undefined results]

[image: undefined]

EDIT 2

It seams that the issue is on server side, while double encoding
here is an extract :

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.mephisto.optimdata.io/search?object_type=machine');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'authorization: JWT '.$accessToken));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $fulfillment = new stdClass();
    $fulfillment->speech = $result;
    $result = new stdClass();
    $result->fulfillment = $fulfillment;
    $result->requete = "machines actives";
    $responseQueryAPI = new stdClass();
    $responseQueryAPI->result = $result;
    echo json_encode($responseQueryAPI);
```

Maybe this is because the curl response is already json? 
The curl response looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Pallet truck",
        "object_type": "machine",
        "object_id": 3279
    },
    {
        "name": "Collaborative Robot",
        "object_type": "machine",
        "object_id": 3273
    },
    {
        "name": "Bender",
        "object_type": "machine",
        "object_id": 3997
    },
```

Comment: seems like JSONception (JSON within JSON .. ), because of the escaped quotes `\"`. You can try JSON.parse on the value of `speech`. Something like `var speech = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(responce).result.fulfillment.speech)`

Comment: yes I think maybe the error to be on server side I will edit with my php code to see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

`name` is just a string, so try to replace

```
for (var key in obj.result.fulfillment.speech) {
    if (obj.result.fulfillment.speech.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(obj.result.fulfillment.speech[key].name.val());
    }
}
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.result.fulfillment.speech.length; ++i) {
    console.log(obj.result.fulfillment.speech[i].name);
}
```

**Edit:**

The response data looks wrong.

I got syntax error with `JSON.parse('{"result":{"fulfillment":{"speech":"[{\"name\":\"Pallet truck\",\"object_type\":\"machine\",\"object_id\":3279}]"}}}');`.

Try to use 
`JSON.parse('{"result":{"fulfillment":{"speech":[{"name":"Pallet truck","object_type":"machine","object_id":3279}]}}}');`.

Comment: still undefined results

Comment: How about `console.log(obj.result.fulfillment.speech)`?

Comment: it display the whole json in console: 
"result":{
  "fulfillment":{
     "speech":"[
{"name":"Pallet truck","object_type":"machine","object_id":3279},  ...

Comment: I guessed that `console.log(obj.result.fulfillment.speech)` is array like `[[ {"name":"Pallet truck","object_type":"machine","object_id":3279},..]`.
So, please try to replace `obj.result.fulfillment.speech` to `obj.result.fulfillment.speech.result.fulfillment.speech`

Comment: I have this issue since hours now...
I'm tired but I wrote this 
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.result.fulfillment.speech.length; ++i) {                
             console.log(obj.result.fulfillment.speech.result.fulfillment.speech); 
            }
It gives : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fulfillment' of undefined
    at Object.success ((index):642)
    at i (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:2)...